# What is the best way of having autocompletion in IDEA for Ammonite scripts

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ammonite

Suppose I do this in my Ammonite script:

```
import ammonite.ops._
```

but I don't have autocompletion in IDEA, because it doesn't know I'm using this dependency from:

```
"com.lihaoyi" %% "ammonite-ops" % "0.7.7"
```

The same can be said when I import some ivy module using this syntax:

```
import $ivy.`com.google.guava:guava:18.0`
```

What is the best way to let IDEA know what dependencies I'm using?

References:

- [Ammonite Documentation](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a module that holds the scripts.

I create a new module by defining a project in SBT and adding the dependencies necessary:

```
projectDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.lihaoyi" %% "ammonite-ops" % "0.7.7"
)
```

Then I have to reimport the SBT project into IDEA.  The process is a little slow, but voilà, I can have autocompletion in my scritps.

I've created also an issue in IDEA for 1st class support of Ammonite.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10752